# Optimal basis generation using simplex

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, optimal-control, simplex, linear-control

Given the objective function $\sum_{i=0}^{i=n} t_i$ (which I want to minimize), constraints $At = u, t \geq 0$ where $A \in m \times n$, and $ n>m$, I'm trying to determine all of the *possible* optimal bases of $t$.

This [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5400664/citations?tabFilter=papers#citations) outlines this process pretty well: the main idea is to use the simplex algorithm, but instead of choosing leaving variables based on ratios from $A$ and $u$, every possible leaving variable is chosen, which results in branching after each iteration. (the point of the paper is to do all this without prior knowledge of $u$)

The physical interpretation of this problem (18 thrusters controlling a spacecraft in 6 DoF) is to find all sets of 6 thrusters that (together) could achieve any control input $u \in \mathbb{R}^6$ (i.e. a 3D force + 3D torque) while minimizing the sum of on-times of the thrusters.

The paper presents a table of 120 optimal thruster combinations for their specific $A$ matrix. (the columns of $A$ represents the force and torque produced by each thruster)

I've written code that works perfectly with relatively small dimension $n = 4$ and $m = 2$, but with $n = 18$ and $m = 6$, but I'm trying to reproduce their optimal thruster table, but running into issues where the program finds a huge number of (supposedly) optimal sets, and eventually runs out of memory from branching too many times.

I've added checks to make sure no optimal sets are being repeatedly found, but the program still appears to be finding lots and lots of unique optimal sets. Basically everything appears to be in working order except the total number of sets I'm finding is way higher than what the paper suggests.

Anyone have any thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Isn't your problem just a linear programming problem?

Comment: Have you checked to see if all the bases you are finding are actually optimal?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen basically except instead of finding an optimal solution for a given $u$ I need to find all the optimal solutions that (combined) span the vector space of $u$.

Comment: @DavidM. Yes, the criteria for storing the solutions checks the objective function coefficients to see if they're all positive, if they are it stores them. I'm storing them as indices and ordering the sets so I don't end up with different permutations of the same sets (e.g. 1,4,6,3,8,12 and 6,8,12,3,1,4).

Comment: Spanning the vector space of $u$ can also be captured in the formulation of a linear programming problem, for example the Matlab function [linprog](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html) allows both linear equality and inequality constraints.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen it looks like i would need to input b though? I need to find optimal sets independent of b.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted yours question. I initially thought that you just want to find the optimal $t$ for a given $A$ and $u$. But you want to find the best $A$ such that the average optimal solution for $t$ is minimized with respect to every possible $u$ (probably constrained such that the two norm of each column of $A$ is one)?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen not quite, I am given A and need to find all of the possible optimal bases. Physically this means that, given a desired torque or force, the optimal combination of thrusters should be 1 of 120 possible optimal sets (the fact that they are specifically 120 optimal sets probably depends on the given value of A). This doesn't specify anything about on-time, but rather just which thrusters will be used.

Comment: In terms of $t$ an optimal set just specifies which entries of $t$ will be greater than 0, but not the actual values. So I should be able to find all possible combination of entries of $t$ greater than 0. So that when I am given $u$ I know that the optimal solution will be one of those combinations, at which point I can easily compute the actual value of $t$ by taking the inverse of the matrix constructed from the corresponding columns of A and multiplying by $u$.